# flat url rewriting: stripped of path in HTML anchor

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In C:\xampp\htdocs\myname\myproject\index.html I have

```
<a href="/aboutus">About Us</a>
```

This should link to C:\xampp\htdocs\myname\myproject\aboutus.html.

In my localhost I would like the url to look like this:

```
localhost/myname/myproject/
localhost/myname/myproject/aboutus
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to write the url rewriting rules to make this work.
The only thing that works is if I put the path in the html:

```
<a href="/myname/myproject/aboutus">About Us</a>
```

But I don't want to do that.

My C:\xampp\htdocs\myname\myproject\.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable url rewriting
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /myname/myproject/

# Don't rewrite explictly requested paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   

# URL rewriting rules
#TEST RewriteRule aboutus /myname/myproject/aboutus.html
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html/$ $1\.html

</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html/$ $1\.html`

to

`RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)/?$ $1\.html`

What you're doing wrong is the regex. You're only allowing the characters 0-9 in your page name. Also notice the `/?` at the end. That's for making the / optional.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling my regex would be wrong.  But the problem seems to go deeper though since even `RewriteRule aboutus aboutus\.html` doesn't work (unless I put the path in the href tag).  It always redirects to http://localhost/xampp/